# Uniqueness of disintegration

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading a paper by Ackerman et al. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02992) on disintegration and computability. Here is the set-up: let $(S,\mathcal{S})$ and $(T,\mathcal{T})$ be two measurable spaces and $\mu$ a probability measure on $S$. Let $\mathcal{M}(S)$ denote the set of probability distributions on $(S,\mathcal{S})$, equipped with the weak topology (and its associated Borel algebra). Finally let $g: (S,\mathcal{S})\rightarrow (T,\mathcal{T})$ be measurable and $\nu=\mu g^{-1}$. We say $\kappa: T\rightarrow \mathcal{M}(S)$ is a *disintegration* of $\mu$ along $g$ if $\kappa$ is measurable and $\int_B\kappa(w)(A)d\nu=\mu(A\cap g^{-1}B)$ for any $A\in\mathcal{T}$ and $B\in\mathcal{S}$.

Now Ackerman et al. claim on p.4 that "any two maps $\kappa, \kappa'$ satisfying the definition of disintegration agree on a $\nu$-measure one set.'' On a straightforward reading, this is saying $\nu\{\omega: \kappa(\omega)=\kappa'(\omega)\}=1$. I know how to prove this if $\mathcal{S}$ is countably generated, but I am not sure how to show this (or whether this is true) when we drop the countably generated condition (and yet I could not find this assumption in their paper). Does anyone have any clue? Many thanks in advance.